# does 12v negative wire amp rating need to match positive

Tags: amperage, 12v

A basic question I am sure but does the amp rating of the negative wire need to match the amp rating of the positive wire used?

I am guessing yes but part of me is thinking no I don't need to match it

Cheers
Mark

Comment: The amp rating needs to match the current that runs through the wire. You can always have one wire have ten times the amps rating needed if you wish to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not match per say, but be sufficiently large for the current.

The current flowing though and heating up the positive wire will flow back though the negative wire and heating it up in the same way. If you select any of them too thinn for the current you run though it, it will overheat.

EDIT: Difference of match as in exact same size and be sufficiently large in area.

Comment: ok great thanks for clarifying. I expected that was the case but wanted to check just in case.

Comment: But they don't need to match; as long as each meets or exceeds the rating.

Comment: No they don't.  They both have to be sufficient for the current being passed, that's all.  If you're passing 1A, and pick a positive wire rated for 10A, then the negative still only has to be rated for 1A.

Comment: They don't need to match. Each only needs to be sufficient for the current.